# JS Best practice for passing argument with bind to function inside object to access specific variable inside objects scope

Tags: javascript, inheritance

If passing into calculate(z) on object a would the bind be considered proper "best practice" for scoping x ?

```
var a = {
    x: 10,
    calculate: function(z){
        return this.x + this.y + z;
    }
};

a.calculate.bind({x:a.x, y:3})(10); // 23
```

Comment: Arrow functions `calculate: (z) => { ... }` are an easy way to do binding...

Comment: `this.x` is already `10` without binding, no? Why don't you just include `y` as an argument? I don't understand this mixing of an object with an `x` property and binding.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn What do you mean? Arrow functions specifically do *not* bind `this`. Also, how would that really help the OP?

Comment: a.calculate.bind({y:3})(12) // NaN

Comment: The shown code does not make to much sense, it is not clear why you want to do a binding on `a.calculate` if you do not save the result of the binding for later use. So for the given code it is a wrong usage of `bind`.

Comment: @jremi That's because you're explicitly binding a new object without `x`. I still don't understand the practical application of this.

Comment: This is just pure trying to understand how you would access the a.x without having to specifiy it via the bind.

Comment: There is no actual pratical use case for this eample . I am just trying to understand why a.calculate when called will not get the this.x  automatically? I need to re-specify the x with the bind to associate it inside the "this" scope

Comment: `a.calculate.bind({y:3})` returns a function whose `this` is `{ y: 3 }`, which causes `this.x === undefined`

Comment: without an arrow function, `calculate: function` has its own `this`, so using an arrow, `this` now references the `a.x` instead of `calculate.x`.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn no it doesn't. If `calculate` was an arrow function, its `this === window`

Comment: Because `calculate` is then called on the object that you specify in bind and doesn't know anything about the `a` anymore. Your code is currently equal to  `a.calculate.call({x:a.x, y:3}, 10)`. This means `calculate`  is called on the object `{x:a.x, y:3}` with the parameter `10`.

Answer (score 2):

No, using `a.calculate.bind({x:a.x, y:3})(10)` is not a best practice. You're looking for [`.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

```
a.calculate.call({x:a.x, y:3}, 10)
```

Comment: Why does it return NaN with your .call syntax?

Comment: Maybe `a.calculate.call(Object.assign({}, a, { y: 3 }), 10)` if there are more properties than `x`? Or `a.calculate.call({ ...a, y: 3 }, 10)` if ES2018 is supported.

Comment: @jremi given your current code, Bergi's answer returns `23`, _not_ `NaN`.

Comment: That is correct. You must use regular function(z){} ... If using (z)=>{} fat arrow fails

Comment: @jremi yes that is correct, [as I pointed out to Get Off My Lawn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51310243/js-best-practice-for-passing-argument-with-bind-to-function-inside-object-to-acc#comment89597366_51310243). Arrow functions and regular functions are not interchangable when dealing with `this`.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts In that case, maybe even `{...a, y:3}.calculate(10)` :-)